# SDL2 on Android, how to catch onResume events?

Tags: android, android-ndk, sdl, activity-lifecycle

I'm trying to makes some project with simply SDL2 on Android.

I've first tried to compile the example given in the archive `tesgesture.c`, you can see [the code here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~bnf/sdl-wayland/tree/test/testgesture.c?id=794c5cb3ee58b4d790ebd1e87da60b40e646609c).

It works fine on my Android phone, but whenever I suspend the application (to launch an other, whatsoever), when I resume it, the application freezes and stops responding (which I think because we haven't reach back the SDL thread).

I've found it's a common issue, but didn't find any clear solution.

I've tried applying [this patch](http://www.union.org.pl/download/sdl/) and the adding those event to my switch:

```
case SDL_SYSEVENT_TERMINATE:
case SDL_SYSEVENT_SUSPEND:
case SDL_SYSEVENT_RESUME :
case SDL_SYSEVENT_WILL_RESUME :
case SDL_SYSEVENT_WILL_SUSPEND:
```

but it doesn't change anything.

I've also seen that it seems the events `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_LOST` are sent when the application is put in the background so I've tested:

```
case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
    if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED ||
            event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_LOST) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    break;
```

without much more success.

So is there somebody who knows how to catch these events?

Comment: I have the same damn problem. And I tried, and still looking for a way to handle this with a call from SDLActiviy.java from a function like onResoume, OnPause...